# How to include shared references in WiX project

Tags: wix

I have a Visual Studio solution with three projects: Core, Application, Setup (WiX). In the setup project I have a separate ComponentGroup for each VS project. These ComponentGroups contain Component for the project output and Components for all its references. For example:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ApplicationComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="Application" Guid="SOME-GUID-1">
    <File Id="ApplicationExe"
          Name="$(var.Application.TargetFileName)"
          Source="$(var.Application.TargetPath)"
          KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ApplicationCommonLogging" Guid="SOME-GUID-2">
    <File Id="ApplicationCommonLoggingDll"
          Name="Common.Logging.dll"
          Source="$(var.Application.TargetDir)Common.Logging.dll"
          KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  ...
</ComponentGroup>
```

However, references to Common.Logging.dll exist in both Core and Application projects, so I get an error like this:

ICE30: The target file '138eezlo.dll|Common.Logging.dll' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyApp\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'CoreCommonLogging' and 'ApplicationCommonLogging'. This breaks component reference counting.

Is there something wrong with the structure of components in my setup project? How and where I should declare Components for Common.Logging and other shared references?

Comment: If these two Logging DLLs are the same file in different components they should share the same GUID at least. ICE30 often happens with merge modules and usually it is safe to ignore so I wouldn't worry about it much if you get it. I would assume CORE is *always* installed so the logging DLL could conceivably only be included once in the Core project.

Comment: Consider using ComponentRef.

Comment: Both components are _always_ installed. Common.Logging.dll is just an example as well as the number of projects. What I'm trying to find is some generic pattern of handling projects' references, so that projects are independent.